# Missing viewport meta tag when deployed to Modulus.io

Tags: node.js, meteor, modulus, modulus.io

I am use Meteor and I verified that everything is working fine when I use meteor deploy but when I deploy to Modulus, the website is missing the viewport meta tag so it's not responsive. Does anyone know the solution or how to approach fixing this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The issue was fixed by setting A-records.

Comment: can you explain in more detail?